# Springboot JDBCTemplate Multiple Database

Tags: java

I have configured two databases (Same schema one is QA and another one is PROD DB) in my Springboot application, The idea here is I don't want to deploy two instances of application to talk to each DB instead on login screen user will select the Database to work with and then application will connect to the database and pull the required data. The question is how can I select database dynamically in my DAO layer using @Qualifier("firstDB") or @Qualifier("secondDB"). Please note that I have user selected database value in Session object so obviously I can't or should not access Session data in my DAO layer as I want to keep DAO separately. Please help me out to choose a DB connection dynamically.

DB Configuration:

```
@Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSourceOne") DataSource dsCustom) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dsCustom);
}
```

**DAO:**

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public TidalAlertsDAOImpl(JdbcTemplate template) {
    this.jdbcTemplate = template;
}
```

Solution:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "dataSourceOne")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("USERNAME")
                .password("Password")
                .url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.com:1521:DV")
                .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceTwo")
    public DataSource dataSourceTwo() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username("USERNAME")
                .password("Password")
                .url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost.com:1521:QA")
                .driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcTemplate")
    @Autowired
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSourceOne") DataSource dsCustom) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsCustom);
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getJDBCTemplate(){
        String environmnet = null;
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = null;
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        HttpSession session = requestAttributes.getRequest().getSession();
        if(session.getAttribute("databaseName") != null){
             environmnet = (String) session.getAttribute("databaseName");
             if(environmnet.equals("Development - QA")){
                 System.out.println("Sected Database is:" + environmnet);
                 jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceTwo());
             }else if(environmnet.equals("Sandbox - DV")){
                 System.out.println("Sected Database is:" + environmnet);
                 jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
             }
        }
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky one. Will there be multiple users logging into the application? In that case, you will have to map the user with the selected connection. It would be difficult to inject a connection in the DAO using annotations since database connections are at an application level. You will have to retrieve the connection to be used for that user and then use the corresponding connection.

Comment: Multiple users will access the application but they don't keyin the user name or anything like that. They just choose the Database from drop down. This is internal application and mostly DB Reads no updates or commits.

Comment: So I am guessing this is on a per request basis. The type connection can be submitted as a parameter when submitting the request and that param can be used to decide which connection to be used (This is a potential security hazard. Again, having the same application talk to both non-prod and prod environment is not a good design per se. I would suggest to create two instances of the application - one for QA and the other for prod if possible).

Comment: I would say even if it's an internal application and has only read access there's a possibility that someone in the future might grant write access to do something. This is just to avoid that. But coming to your actual question the solution could be passing the connection type in the request as a parameter and then mapping it to the corresponding connection.

Comment: I think I figured the way, Here is how it works. Please let me know if there is better way. Please check original post for latest code. Specially the method getJDBCTemplate().

Comment: That looks okay to me. Although you might want to create a single instance of both the JDBC templates using data source one and two instead of initializing a new JDBC template every time the getJdbcTemplate() method is called.

Comment: Thanks that's good idea. How can I achieve this any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202239/discussion-between-gsr-and-ice-king).